# Swagger openapi 3.0.2 , one path with two get requests that have different params and server

Tags: swagger, openapi

I have an openapi 3.0.2 json.

This api uses 2 different server urls.
Is it possible to have two GET requests on the same path but with different servers and params?

If not, what alternative do I have?

Below is a minimal example:

```
{
  "openapi": "3.0.2",
  "info": {
    "title": "test API",
    "version": "1.0"
  },
  "servers": [
    { "url": "https://test-api.us.core.com/tests1/v1" },
    { "url": "https://test-api.eu.core.com/testserver2/v1" }
  ],
  "paths": {
    "/devices": {
      "get": {
        "servers": [
          {
            "url": "https://test-api.eu.core.com/testserver2/v1"
          }
        ],
        "operationId": "getDevices2",
        "parameters": [...],
        "requestBody":{},
        "responses": {...},
        "security": [...]
      },
      "get": {
        "servers": [
          {
            "url": "https://test-api.us.core.com/tests1/v1"
          }
        ],
        "operationId": "getDevices1",
        "parameters": [...],
        "requestBody":{},
        "responses": {...},
        "security": [...]
      },
```